# How to make the read function not to hang?

Tags: c++, serial-port, posix, virtual-serial-port

I'm using socat to create a virtual serial port with:

```
socat PTY,link=/dev/ttySV0,echo=1 PTY,link=/dev/ttySV1,echo=1
```

The in my program written in C++, I open the ttySV1 port and start to read.

The read function is in a while, but the problem is that the read function hangs until I send data to the port. Do you know how to make the taht function not to hang and just exit if there is no data in the buffer?

EDIT: I send data to the port using:

```
echo [data] > /dev/ttySV0
```

Comment: Either use a peek function, or multi-thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a system read function depending on the operating system you are running.
The details should be under man (3) read.

You would have to set O_NONBLOCK using fnctl. This should cause your read to fail if the pipe / FIFO is currently empty. I checked the man pages for Linux but their should be similar behaviors in most POSIX based systems.

Comment: Awesome! I was using exactly that read funcion (my OS is Arch Linux). The difference is that the O_NONBLOCK option was missing. Now I put it and it is working like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that worked.  I love dealing with systems APIs and their hidden options and controls : )

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the select() method to see if there is data to be read. [This](http://cscene.unitycode.org/topics/unix/cs2-13.xml.html) or something else found on google (I searched for "bsd sockets select") should lead you down the right path.